# How to do something when a REDIS want to expire

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have a `key/value` with expire date in `laravel` like this:

```
Redis::set($key, $val, 'EX', 35);
```

now I want to have a closure function when my key/value want to expire.
on the other hand I want to do something when expiration occurs.

Comment: You don't. Redis is a key/value store and doesn't expose to you the ability to use closures or implement observables. Instead, you could dispatch a job that has delayed execution equal to the redis expiration timeout and perform your logic in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `psubscribe`

```
$redis = new \Redis();
$redis->setOption();
$redis->psubscribe(array('__keyevent@0__:expired'), 'keyCallback');
function keyCallback($redis, $pattern, $chan, $msg)
{
    echo "Pattern: $pattern\n";
    echo "Channel: $chan\n";
    echo "Payload: $msg\n\n";
}
```